# ¿Cómo usar correctamente la función gethostbyaddr() en C?

Tags: c, socket, ip

Creé un protocolo basado en sockets y lo estoy implementando en C: una vez uniciado el servidor hay que iniciar el cliente pasándole como primer y único parámetro el nombre de la máquina en la que se encuentra corriendo el servidor, pero como no funciona con DNS, es necesario modificar el archivo `/etc/hosts` en el cliente para asignarle un nombre a la IP del servidor. Para evitar toda esta configuración manual, estoy tratando de que el cliente requiera como único parámetro la IP real del servidor, probé usar la función `gethostbyaddr()` en vez de la función `gethostbyname()`, que era la que estaba usando, el servidor arrancó correctamente, pero cuando quise iniciar el cliente pasándole como único parámetro la dirección IP real del servidor me saltó una "*Violación de segmento*". ¿Alguién me podría ayudar con mi problema? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Cliente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int stsocket, stport;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[2048];
    if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0 || argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
    {
        printf("Uso: %s [opciones] host\nOpciones:\n\t-h, --help\tMuestra esta ayuda.\n\nEl argumento <host> es el nombre del host a conectarse. El cliente se conectará al puerto 3890 de este.\n\nEstado de salida:\n\t0 si todo fue bien.\n\t1 si no se pudo crear el socket.\n\t2 si no se especificó un host.\n\t3 si el host no es válido.\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    stport = 3890;
    stsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("300 - No se especificó un host.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (socket < 0)
    {
        printf("201 - No se pudo crear el socket.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    server = gethostbyaddr (inet_addr(argv[1]), sizeof(argv[1]), AF_INET);
    if (server < 0)
    {
        printf("301 - El host %s no es válido.\n", argv[1]);
        return 3;
    }
    bzero((char *) &address, sizeof(address));
    addres.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&address.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    address.sin_port = htons(mdport);
    connect(stsocket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address));
    printf("101 - Conectado. (STTP/1.0)\n");
    printf("Ingrese el mesaje a enviar al servidor: ");
    bzero(buffer, 2048);
    fgets(buffer, 2047, stdin);
    write(stsocket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    bzero(buffer, 2048);
    read(stsocket, buffer, 2047);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    close(stsocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Servidor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int stsocket, new_stsocket, stport, n;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[2048];
    struct sockaddr_in address, cli_addr;
    if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0 || argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
    {
        printf("Uso: %s [opciones]\nOpciones:\n\t-h, --help\tMuestra esta ayuda.\n\nEstado de salida:\n\t0 si todo fue bien.\n\t1 si el puerto necesario no está disponible.\n\t2 si no se pudo escribir o leer el socket.\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    stsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero((char *) &address, sizeof(address));
    stport = 3890;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    address.sin_port = htons(stport);
    n = bind(stsocket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)); 
    if (n < 0)
    {
        write(new_stsocket, "202 - El puerto necesario no está disponible.\n", 56);
        printf("202 - El puerto necesario no está disponible.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    listen(stsocket, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    new_stsocket = accept(stsocket, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    printf("101 - Conectado %s:3890. (STTP/1.0)\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
    bzero(buffer, 2048);
    n = read(new_stsocket, buffer, 2047);
    printf("Mensaje del cliente: %s", buffer);
    n = write(new_stsocket, "100 - Mensaje recibido.", 29);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        write(new_stsocket, "200 - No se pudo escribir o leer el socket.\n", 55);
        printf("200 - No se pudo escribir o leer el socket.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    printf("100 - Mensaje recibido.\n");
    close(new_stsocket);
    close(stsocket);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar dónde te da la violación de segmento? Poniendo un par de `printf` y viendo cual es el último.

Comment: Muy bien, lo hice y la violación de segmento salta, al parecer, justo al principio del programa ya que no actúa siquiera el primer `printf();`. Supongo que el problema es con los parámetros.

Comment: Eso es muy raro, en general no veo nada en el principio del programa que parezca erróneo. ¿Puedes indicar exactamente hasta donde llega la ejecución? Nota: si tienes disponible un depurador, la ejecución paso por paso te permitirá verlo todo con más detalle.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, probé con el _gdb_ y parece ser que el error está en que a una de las bibliotecas  que incluí le falta un archivo, no tenía que ver con el código. La diferencia entre el código con la función `gethostbyname` era que no tenía que llamar a la función `inet_addr();`, que está en el archivo inet_addr.c, el archivo que falta en la biblioteca.